# iTunes Connect attach a contract that proofs rights

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an application in which I display a third part content. But, I have a contract that give me the rights to use that third part content.

I am trying to find where I can attach a copy of that contract in the itunes connect before I submit the IPA with no success.

Can someone point that place for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it. You are asked some question when you are trying to submit app for review. one of the if you remember is about Advertising Identifier (IDFA).

And the other is about the content rights:

[image]

May be we don't have to attach the document now. only when someone proceeds with a law suit against us :)